# (Lotto 6/49 simulation) Calculate how many draws will take place until a user-entered combination hits the jackpot

Tags: c

I have my code and data for my Lotto 6/49 simulation. **I just don't know how to create a simple mathematical expression to calculate how many draws will take place until the user hits the jackpot**

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     //need this library to use srand and rand without warnings
#include <time.h>       //need this library to use time function
int main(void) {
    int i, j, k , temp, count1=0;
    unsigned int count2=1;
    int select[6];
    int jackpot[6];
    printf("Welcome to Lotto 6/49! The 6 numbers you choose must match the 6 randomly chosen numbers in the lottery in order to win the jackpot. Select your 6 numbers!\n\n");
    for(i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter a number between 1-49: ");
        scanf("%d", &select[i]);
    }
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(;;){
        for(i=0; i!= 6 ; )  //This loop produces the winning number combination
        {
            temp= (rand() %49)+1;  //produce a random number between 1 and 49
            for( k =0 ; k<i && (temp!=jackpot[k]) ; k++);  //make sure we do not have duplicate

            if (k==i){      //only write to the array if we do not have a duplicate
                jackpot[i] = temp;
                i++;                //only increment the loop if we write a value to the array
            }
        }
        printf("\nThe winning numbers are: ");  //displays the winning numbers
        for(i=0;i<6;i++)
            printf("\t%d\t",jackpot[i]);
        printf("\n");
        // This loop will check the user array with the jackpot array to determine if it is a winning combination
        for(i=0; i<6 && i ==count1; i++){ //if we do not match the first element, we skip the rest
            for(j=0; j<6 ; j++)
            {
                if(select[i]==jackpot[j]){
                    count1+=1;      // only increment if we match
                }
            }
        }
        if(count1==6){ //all 6 numbers matched
            printf("\n\nYou win the JACKPOT! Congratulations! \nIt took you %d draws to win", count2);
            break;
        }
        else{
        count2+=1;
        count1=0;   //reset match count
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Data (number range limited to 8 numbers for easier recording, eg **temp= (rand() %8)+1** instead of temp= (rand() %49)+1 @ **line 19**.)

Count1 = user input matched

Count2 = # of draws 
[image]

```
                                                 ↑
                                 I have no clue how to calculate this
```

Comment: @user3386109 I think the asker is supposed to be doing a Monte Carlo simulation and counting the attempts.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica What does the big bold line right at the top of the question say?

Comment: @user3386109 But you can't calculate how many it "will" take like that, since there's a random element.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  With an honest, random lottery, it is impossible to predict how many draws it will take to hit a set of numbers.  The image shows the results of a simulation run, not a prediction.  It looks like you are saying you have no clue how to calculate how many draws it took, but your code appear to count draws and report the number.  (I haven't checked if it works.)  Your chances of getting help will be better if you can explain more.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Sure, but you can still do the math to figure out the probability distribution, and the expected number of draws before winning. In fact, the people who design lotteries **have** to do that math. Otherwise, they end up paying out more money than they take in. There was a news story a few years back about a lottery in the northeastern US that **wasn't** designed properly, and some kids at MIT exploited that to make millions of dollars.

Comment: They weren't using precise terminology when they said "how many draws." Precise terms would be, "What is the _expected value_ of the number of draws it would take to win?" [Expected Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) simply means, if you simulated a large number of parallel universes, what would the average number of draws converge toward. That's where code comes in: you can simulate a ton of "parallel universes" (this is also known as "Monte Carlo simulation") and keep track of how many draws, to compute an (approximate) average in the end.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the expected value is even what they're supposed to be calculating. I think they're supposed to be doing just one random simulation, and returning the result. (Think "Roll a die and tell me what you get" vs. "Tell me the average result of rolling a die".)

Comment: From the comment stream, it would appear that the question has not been asked with sufficient clarity to generate an answer.